# What's the sequence of events from the .NET GC's point of view that causes premature collection when in unmanaged code?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I'm really struggling to grasp premature garbage collection between managed / unmanaged code in .NET and am wondering if anyone here has a good way to explain it.

The bug we had was similar to the one described here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/246372/Premature-NET-garbage-collection-or-Dude-wheres-my

Basically we are calling a method on an object that calls into unmanaged code; the managed object underpinning it gets GC'd and its finalizer is called; the GC.KeepAlive is needed to stop this from happening:

(code taken from the linked article):

```
Foo a = new Foo();
while (true)
{
    FooBar b = new FooBar();
    b.WorkWith(a);
    GC.KeepAlive(b);
}
```

Now, I understand that the GC.KeepAlive is needed, but I don't understand how the GC comes to the conclusion that b can be discarded without the KeepAlive.  Doesn't the runtime know that b is in the middle of executing a method, even if it is a method that's gone into native code (specifically that 'b' has been used as a this reference in a method call)?

Why is 'b' eligible for collection on entry to the WorkWith(..) and why wouldn't the garbage collector instead assume that 'b' could be made eligible on exit of the WorkWith method?

What am I missing? How does this actually play out?

**UPDATE** Thanks everyone for your answers.  I feel like I understand this much better now.  Still trying to work out a nice solution for our particular API but I think I'll leave that for a separate question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While things are slightly complicated by virtual method dispatch, an instance method behaves largely like a static method where `this` is passed as the first parameter.  Thus, within class `Foo`, that has field `int Bar` a method

```
void SetBar(int newBar) { Bar = newBar; }
```

is internally equivalent to:

```
static void SetBar(Foo This, int newBar) { This.Bar = newBar; }
```

If `Foo` were a field called `MyBitmap` which held an `IntPtr` handle to an unmanaged bitmap, and had a method like:

```
// Should call GC.SuppressFinalize, but doesn't.
static Byte[] ExportBitmapDataAndDispose(Foo This)
{
  IntPtr myBits = This.MyBitMap;
  if (myBits == 0) throw new ObjectDisposedException(...);
  int destSize = ExternalBitmapHandler.GetSize(myBits);
  var result = new Byte[destSize];
  ExternalBitmapHandler.CopyBits(myBits, ref result[0], destSize);
  ExternalBitmapHandler.ReleaseBits(myBits);
  myBits = 0;
}
```

the compiler would see that `This` was never used after field `MyBitMap` was read from it.  The code still has need of the external resources which are identified by `myBits`, but the garbage collector knows nothing of such things.  From its perspective, if the object referred to by `This` has no other live references, code shouldn't care whether those objects simply ceased to exist at that point or were kept around longer.  Indeed, its assumption is correct in that the running code would indeed not care about when such objects ceased to exist.  Unfortunately, in the presence of finalizers, objects don't just cease to exist.  Instead, if the garbage-collector notices that the Finalization Queue holds the only live reference to `This`, it may running `This.Finalize()`, which may in turn notify `ExternalBitmapHandler` that the bitmap identified by `myBits` is no longer required.

Note that the problem isn't actually with the *garbage collection* of `This`, but rather with the *Finalization* of `This`.  Finalization is *not* garbage-collection but is instead an operation which is triggered when the GC discovers an object which would be eligible for immediate annihilation *were it not for the registered finalizer*.  Another way to look at it would be to say that `ExternalBitmapHandler` should be notified when the bitmap identified by `This.MyBitMap` is no longer required, but the only thing the garbage-collector can tell is when `This` is no longer required.  Once the code has read `This.MyBitMap` into `myBits`, it no longer needs `This` and would be perfectly happy if `This` ceased to exist, provided it didn't clobber the bitmap referred to by `myBits.  An alternative version of the code might be:

```
static Byte[] ExportBitmapDataAndDispose(Foo This)
{
  IntPtr myBits = System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref This.MyBitMap, 0);
  GC.SuppressFinalize(This);
  if (myBits == 0) throw new ObjectDisposedException(...);

  int destSize = ExternalBitmapHandler.GetSize(myBits);
  try
  {
    var result = new Byte[destSize]; // Could throw OutOfMemoryException
    ExternalBitmapHandler.CopyBits(myBits, ref result[0], destSize);
  }
  finally
  {
    ExternalBitmapHandler.ReleaseBits(myBits);
  }
}
```

Note that in this case there is no `KeepAlive`, nor is the `SuppressFinalize` code put at the end where it would defer any possibility of finalization until everything was complete.  Once the `Interlocked.Exchange` has occurred, there would be nothing wrong with the system destroying `This`, since it would no longer needed for anything; the system will need to keep it around long enough to perform `SuppressFinalize`, but after that it could disappear and nobody would notice.

Comment: And this, class, is why you shouldn't have finalizers for anything that doesn't directly manage a native resource.  And just as importantly, why if you must finalize, you shouldn't `Dispose` runtime-managed resources that can have escaped -- they'll take care of themselves once they're no longer needed.

Comment: @cHao: I've sometimes wondered if .NET would have been better if, instead of having objects include a `Finalizer` method, `Object` included a constructor overload with a "cleanup" delegate which would run when the object *was collected*, and which for proper operation would be required not to hold any strong reference back to its owner (the system would have a static strong reference to all such delegates).  Such a design would prevent objects from triggering their finalizers and then being resurrected (possibly entirely outside their control), but would not interfere with most "useful"...

Comment: ...resurrection scenarios, which are generally more interested in recycling resources than preserving the object identities which nobody cared about.  Some care would still be needed to ensure proper "keepalive" usage, but moving cleanup logic outside the object to be cleaned up would help promote proper usage patterns.

Answer (score 3):

The jitter generates an internal table that describes where local variables are stored and when they start and stop storing an object reference.  That table will say that the `b` variable stops being relevant at the WorkWith call.  It generated the *this* argument that's passed to the instance method and is no longer used afterwards, including the method call itself.

It is now up to the WorkWith() method to track the usage of the *this* object reference.  If that method is actually implemented in native code then there may well be a problem, such code is not jitted so there's no table that describes when *this* is still relevant.

Accordingly, the `b` object can be garbage collected *while* the native code is running.  it will happen when another thread in the program triggers a GC.

The GC.KeepAlive() call modifies that table, extending it past the method call.  There is ultimately a flaw in the code we cannot see, probably some kind of C++/CLI code that interops with native code.  It should be *that* code that takes care of the reference.  This is often fumbled, using GC.KeepAlive() is a valid workaround for such a bug.

You can perhaps contact the owner of this component and recommend he uses the [`gcManagedToUnmanaged` debugger assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya4zeek2.aspx) to flush out bugs like this.  It works by intentionally forcing a garbage collection on a transition into unmanaged code.